# Running a shell script through Fabric which wants to run a background running command

Tags: python, shell, amazon-web-services, fabric

I am a newbie in **Fabric,** and want to run one command in a background, it is written in shell script, and I have to run that command via Fabric, so lets assume I have a command in shell script as:

```
#!/bin/bash/
java  &
```

Consider this is a file named **myfile.sh**

Now in **Fabric** I am using this code to run my script as:

```
put('myfile.sh', '/root/temp/')
sudo('sh /root/temp/myfile.sh')
```

Now this should start the Java process in background but when I login to the Machine and see the jobs using **jobs** command, nothing is outputted.

Where is the problem please shed some light.

Comment: Try using `ps` instead of `jobs` to see processes, e.g. `ps -aef` or `ps aux`

Comment: used that as  well, no success, in fact my doubt is whether the procedure I am following is correct or not. Or is there any other process

Comment: Well you could remove `/root/temp/myfile.sh` and run your Fabric command and then see if the file is created.

Comment: You could add a new second line into `my file.sh` that does `date > /tmp/started` so you can see if it started.

Comment: You could change `sudo ('sh` to `sudo('/bin/bash`

Comment: I am able to run the command in background using this: run('nohup myfile.sh',pty=False);  but now the Fabric prompt is waiting for the command inside the shell script to wait, how to execute next command in Fabric without waiting for the background process after execution..

Comment: run('nohup myfile.sh &',pty=False);

Comment: For example: run('nohup PATH_TO_JMETER/Jmetercommand &', pty=False), runs the command, but keeps on waiting for it to complete, this is the problem. how to come back after running a background process

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52373/discussion-between-ankur-verma-and-mark-setchell)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it with

```
run('nohup PATH_TO_JMETER/Jmetercommand & sleep 5; exit 0)
```

Comment: missing a single quote somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

maybe the process exists before you return. when you type in java, normally it shows up help message and exits. Try a sleep statement or something that lingers. and if you want to run it in the background, you could also append & to the sudo call

Comment: The command I used is just an example, actually I want to run the  JMeter script to start executing

Answer (score 1):

I use `run("screen -d -m sh /root/temp/myfile.sh",pty=False)`. This starts a new [screen](http://ss64.com/bash/screen.html) session in detached mode, which will continue running after the connection is lost. I use the `pty=False` [option](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run) because I found that when connecting to several hosts, the process would not be started in all of them without this option.